# When I am installing Nvidia driver and Cuda, CentOS 7 cannot boot [image]

Tags: centos, nvidia-graphics-card, centos-7, cuda

What is the reason preventing CentOS7 to boot when installing Nvidia driver and Cuda.

I have tried two times. The first time only installed the driver and then when I restart the computer it hangs on the following screen. The second time I used yum directly installed Cuda which also will install the driver, everything goes will and installed successfully, but again the same error happened.

[image]

One of the [tutorials](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-on-centos-7-linux) I have followed